# Play Framework 2.1 - template arguments type parameters

Tags: playframework-2.0, template-engine, type-parameter, playframework-2.1

In my template I would like to use a bounded type parameter instead of an exact type:

```
@(myForm: Form[T])
```

where `T` is like `T <: MyType`

so as to make it more generic in use. However, I cannot find a way to specify this kind of behavior. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
Form[_ <: MyType]
```

That way you can pass in any `Form` with a type parameter that extends MyType.